Probability winning game where you order random variables as you go along
Let us pick $n$ independent random variables from $U[0,1]$, one at a time. After you see what $X_1$ is, you have to guess what position it will come in out of $n$. Then you see what $X_2$ is and have to guess what position that will come in. You win if you guess everything correctly. The distribution doesn't actually matter as long as it's continuous, because we only care about order.
E.g. if $n=10$ and $X_1=0.7$ you might want to guess it will come $7$th. But if $X_4=0.7$ and your top three positions have all been used up (you can't win if you guess the same position twice) you might instead want to guess it comes $5$th.
I would like to know the probability $\alpha_n$ of winning this game if you play optimally.

My progress:
Each turn in the game splits the game into two subgames. Suppose $n=10$ turn one you observe $X_1=0.6$ and put it in position $7$. Then you win the game if and only if exactly $3$ of the remaining $9$ numbers are more than $0.6$, and if we correctly order both the three numbers that are more than $0.6$ and the $6$ numbers that are less than $0.6$ as we go along. This has probability $\binom{9}{3}0.6^6\cdot 0.4^3$ multiplied by $\alpha_3$ multiplied by $\alpha_6$.
So our probability of winning given $X_1$, playing optimally, is
$$\max_{r}\binom{n-1}{r}x_1^{r-1} (1-x_1)^{n-r} \alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}$$
And so we can find a recursion relation for $\alpha$:
$$\alpha_n=\int_0^1 \max_{r}\binom{n-1}{r}x_1^{r-1} (1-x_1)^{n-r} \alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r} dx_1$$
but this doesn't seem very helpful. I think if I knew more about what the optimal strategy was this could be used to simplify the expression.
It seems a very natural problem, and we know the answer will be a rational number so I would hope for a closed form, or at least a recursion relation.
The cutoff point between choosing $r$ and $r+1$ is
$$\binom{n-1}{r}x_1^{r-1}(1-x_1)^{n-r}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}
=\binom{n-1}{r+1}x_1^r(1-x_1)^{n-r-1}\alpha_r\alpha_{n-r-1}$$
Which simplifies to
$$\frac{(r+1)(n-r-2)}{r(n-r-1)}\cdot \frac{1-x_1}{x_1}\cdot \frac{\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}}{\alpha_r\alpha_{n-r-1}}=1$$
This means in the case $n=3$ the cutoffs are $\frac{3}{11}$ and $\frac{8}{11}$. $\alpha_3$ can then be computed to be $\frac{4147}{6\cdot 11^3}$.

Intuitively, for the first step, we should just pick the most likely location of that first number... regardless of $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_6$. Can we prove that?

I think you should start by finding the strategies and success probabilities for small numbers.  For $2$ you should guess it is highest if it is greater than $\frac 12$ and your winning probability is $\frac 34$ because if the first number is near the end you win with high likelihood.

Then for $3$ if the first one is the middle and you guess it you certainly win.  If it is one end and you guess that you win with probability $\frac 34$.  Now you can look for where  the cutoff should be to guess the first number is an end.

I don't think it is likely that the answer is rational. The cutoff point from where $r$ is better than $r-1$ is the zero of some polynomial with large exponents for large $n$ and $r$.

The standard literature is: "The best choice problem"
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spa.2021.12.008
"Who solved the secretary problem?"
https://doi.org/10.1214/ss/1177012493
"Diffuse models for sampling and predictive interference"
https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176344377 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem

@VezenBU For $n=3$ the optimal cutoff points turn out to be $\frac{3}{11}$ and $\frac{8}{11}$ so that is not the case. In fact, it seems nontrivial to prove that every number $r$ will have some region where $r$ is the optimal guess.

@RossMillikan I have now computed the optimal strategy and probability for $n=3$, but it quickly becomes very messy. I might write a python script for it.

It does, in fact, become very messy very quickly :).  See my answer and comment.

You've pretty much done all the hard work.  (I think you have a calculation error in your last step, which makes that result appear a bit more complicated than necessary.)  Let $x_r(n)$ be the optimal cutoff for guessing $r$, for $r=1,2,\ldots,n-1$; you'll have $x_0=0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \ldots \le x_{n-1} \le 1=x_n$, and your guess will be $r$ exactly when the randomly chosen point $x$ is between $x_{r-1}$ and $x_r$.  In each such case, you're guessing that $r-1$ of the remaining $n-1$ points will be less than $x$: your probability of winning will be ${{n-1}\choose{r-1}} x^{r-1} (1-x)^{n-r}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}$. The overall probability of winning is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_n &=& \int_{0}^{1} {{n-1}\choose{r-1}} x^{r-1} (1-x)^{n-r}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}dx \\ &=& \sum_{r=1}^{n}{{n-1}\choose{r-1}}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}\int_{x_{r-1}}^{x_r}  x^{r-1} (1-x)^{n-r}dx \\
&=& \sum_{r=1}^{n}{{n-1}\choose{r-1}}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}\left[B_{x_r}(r, n-r+1) - B_{x_{r-1}}(r, n-r+1)\right],
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where in the first expression, $r$ is being treated as a function of $x$.  The incomplete beta function $B_x(a,b)$ is a rational polynomial for any integer $(a,b)$, so this is certainly a rational number provided that the $x_r(n)$ and the previous $\alpha$'s are rational.  If desired, this can be written as a double sum:
$$
\alpha_n = \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}(n-1)!}{(r-1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\frac{(-1)^j\left[x_r^{r+j} - x_{r-1}^{r+j}\right]}{(n-r-j)!j!(r+j)}.
$$
The endpoints $x_r(n)$ are given by solving the equation
$$
{{n-1}\choose{r-1}}\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}x^{r-1}(1-x)^{n-r}={{n-1}\choose{r}}\alpha_r\alpha_{n-r-1}x^r(1-x)^{n-r-1},
$$
which yields
$$
r(1-x)\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}=(n-r)x\alpha_r\alpha_{n-r-1},
$$
or
$$
x_r(n) = \frac{r\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r}}{r\alpha_{r-1}\alpha_{n-r} + (n-r)\alpha_r\alpha_{n-r-1}}.
$$
For an example, note that $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=1$, and $\alpha_2=3/4$ as mentioned in a comment, so
$$
x_1(3)=\frac{\alpha_0\alpha_2}{\alpha_0\alpha_2+2\alpha_1^2}=\frac{3/4}{3/4+2}=\frac{3}{11}
$$
and
$$
x_2(3)=\frac{2\alpha_1^2}{2\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2\alpha_0}=\frac{2}{2+3/4}=\frac{8}{11}
$$
as claimed in the question.

I've written a short Python implementation of this.  The values of $\alpha(n)$ for small $n$ are: $\alpha(1)=1$, $\alpha(2)=3/4$, $\alpha(3)=377/726$, and (assuming no errors!) $\alpha(4)=1037891564126671/3020778029791104$.  For $n=4$, the cutoff $x_1(4)=754/4021$.
